# how to yum install perl(IPC::Run) on oracle linux 9

Tags: package-management, dnf

I want to yum install postgresql15-devel.x86_64 on oracle linux 9

```shellsession
[root@node1 ~]# yum install -y postgresql15-devel.x86_64 
Last metadata expiration check: 23:26:01 ago on Tue 17 Oct 2023 11:09:23 PM CST.
Error: 
 Problem: cannot install the best candidate for the job
  - nothing provides perl(IPC::Run) needed by postgresql15-devel-15.4-1PGDG.rhel9.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Then i try

```
yum install -y perl-IPC-Run
```

but it shows

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:13:14 ago on Wed 18 Oct 2023 11:26:23 PM CST.
No match for argument: perl-IPC-Run
Error: Unable to find a match: perl-IPC-Run
```

Please tell me how to install `perl-IPC-Run` package on Oracle Linux 9.

Comment: There's no `postgresql15-devel.x86_64` in oracle linux 9. So, that's not something you're installing from Oracle Linux, but from some other package repository. We don't know where from! So we can't help you . **Edit** your question to state exactly what you did to add that repository.

Comment: It would also be a good idea to explain why you need to install a different version of postgresql than what Oracle Linux ships. That might be important!

Comment: because I want to use "repmgr" to control switchover and failover on postgresql 15 but repmgr need postgresql15-devel.x86_64 package...

repmgr is Replication Manager for PostgreSQL clusters

Comment: That sadly still doesn't tell us how you got that postgresql15.

Comment: Sorry
I got the postgresql15 from https://www.postgresql.org/download/
like this

dnf install -y https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-9-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm

dnf install -y postgresql15-server

Comment: **Edit** your question to state exactly what you did to add that repository.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable "Oracle Linux 9 CodeReady Builder (x86_64) - (Unsupported)" repository in **/etc/yum.repos.d/oracle-linux-ol9.repo** , as it is disabled by default.

Then postgresql15-devel installs as expected.

Comment: This answer is a bit short, as it was flagged, but it is correct, because installation is handled by the Package Manager  Thanks for posting it!

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. Unfortunately couldn't solve through yum.
This is what I did. I downloaded the rpm from postgres

```
wget https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/15/redhat/rhel-9-x86_64/postgresql15-devel-15.5-1PGDG.rhel9.x86_64.rpm
```

and then installed it ignoring the dependency.

```
rpm -ivh --nodeps postgresql15-devel-15.5-1PGDG.rhel9.x86_64.rpm
```

This has no effect on the package and using it in the compilation. Hopefully postgres rectify this issue in future.